# Using Arcade expression to obtain X and Y values from geometry of Map Service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-pro, popup, map-service, arcade

I am trying to set up an expression for use in a pop-up in my portal web map in point feature class (image) service that was published referencing SDE Enterprise Feature Class.

When building the expressions I should be getting a value from

```
Geometry($feature).x
```

However when I test this expression I get an error that the member x cannot be called.  Same happens when trying x or y z or calling those methods on Point function.

> Execution Error:Runtime Error: Cannot call member method on null. x

The strange thing is that i remember this working but I wonder if the problem is that our data is now in an enterprise SDE rather that an image service published from the desktop from File Geodatabase. That seems to be the only difference, however documentation says that this should be working.

Similarly, I also cannot obtain values in Arcade from Length or Area functions although I do not get an error when I test those functions. Rather the value the test retrieves is 0

```
Length(Geometry($feature), 'meters')
```

> results in values: 0 when tested
>
> shows no (empty) values in the popup itsef

I can't see what the issue is and seek some insight / workaround.  I was excited to use Arcade expressions in popups instead of field values especially to get coordinates of points since those values unlike Area and Length have to be added as static calculated field = not a good solution.  Being able to obtain those values with Arcade would be nice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Though not documented, it appears that Arcade geometry is not supported for Map Image Services, only Feature services. This is unfortunate since map image services is where i would most often want to use custom popups for majority of users whereas we use feature services when higher level users edit and create data and in those web maps we do not use popups.